# non-greedy to left regexp

Tags: regex, pcre, non-greedy

```
echo LOLbbbbbbLOLccccccSEXddddddLOLeeeeeeLOL|grep -oP 'LOL.*?SEX.*?LOL'
```

outputs LOLbbbbbbLOLccccccSEXddddddLOL

what I expect is LOLccccccSEXddddddLOL - "SEX" surrounded by closest "LOL"

how to achieve this by regexp (grep or perl)?

Comment: What grep version do you use? For me `echo LOLbbbbbbLOLccccccSEXddddddLOLeeeeeeLOL|grep -oP 'lol.*?SEX.*?lol'` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It's must be because it's case sensitive for you and not case sensitive for xoid.

Comment: sorry guys . I fixed the case ussues in Q

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ echo LOLbbbbbbLOLccccccSEXddddddLOLeeeeeeLOL | grep -P --color "LOL[a-z]+SEX[a-z]+LOL"
```